# My recycler view is not show all image and text it only show last image and name "arraylist.size" time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

My Recycler view in image and name which is contained in ArrayList it not show particular like ArrayList in containing all image and name and the last image and name show "ArrayList.size" times like I enter four images and four names so last input image and last input name are shown in recycler view four times.

fragment.java class:

```
public class Revfragment extends Fragment {

    public Revfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ArrayList<gettersetter> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    CustomeAepter customeAepter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String  name[] = {"kishan","karan","jigar","raman"};
    int img[] = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.ad,R.drawable.ac,R.drawable.ab};

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       initDataset();
    }

    private void initDataset() {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        gettersetter gettersetter = new gettersetter(img[i], name[i]);
        arrayList.add(gettersetter);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_revfragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.revs);
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        customeAepter = new CustomeAepter(getActivity(),arrayList);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(customeAepter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
       return rootview;

    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class CustomeAepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomeAepter.myclass> {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    ArrayList<gettersetter> arrayList;
   Context context;


    public CustomeAepter(Context cotexts,ArrayList<gettersetter> arrayLists) {
        arrayList = arrayLists;
        context = cotexts;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomeAepter.myclass onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.textitem,parent,false);
        return new myclass(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomeAepter.myclass holder, int position) {
        holder.getTextView().setText(gettersetter.getName());
        holder.getImageView().setImageResource(gettersetter.getImg());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class myclass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public myclass(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
           imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
        public ImageView getImageView()
        {
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: fragment show this type of recycler view show Image]

Comment: In your onBindViewholder your data should be a function of the position, However you are just setting the same data. Also it seems that gettersetter is a class name. And not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the arraylist in your Adapter. You have to set the value according to the item at corresponding adapter position. Change you `onBindViewHolder` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomeAepter.myclass holder, int position) {
    holder.getTextView().setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.getImageView().setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getImg());
}
```

By this your data will be set according to the items at positions in the list you have passed to the adapter.